# 2 variable foreach loop in Velocity Template Language

Tags: foreach, velocity

Is there any way to use 2 variables in foreach loop ?

```
#foreach( $name in $names &&  $method in $methods )
$name  : $method
#end
```

Because I want to print the result side by side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, just put in the Map

```
Map<String, String> maps = new HashMap<>();

ctx.put("rows",  maps);
```

and iterate over key in maps

```
#foreach( $key in $rows.keySet() )
 Key: $key  Value: $rows.get($key)
#end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over an index.

Assuming both collections have the same size:

```
#set($size = $names.size - 1)
#foreach( $i in [0..$size])
  $names[$i] : $methods[$i]
#end
```

*(edited for correctness)*

Comment: sorry, may i know why u put 0 in the array ? because when i tried it throw an error

Comment: Lexical error,   Encountered: "i" (105), after : ""

Comment: @HydrogenUranium sorry this was a typo. I start at 0 because I assumed your collections where arrays or list. In Java, the indexes are 0-based. But you found a great solution.

Comment: oh I see, ok now I understand , thanks for your help